# align those rows in single line in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

*Need to align those rows in single line in a row like the image shown above.
Tried using align widget but every time it puts the widgets
at the end need to place that dotted border and text right next with in a row. Need help with this. Below is the code Please help. Thanks.*

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Track Order')),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text(
            'Order ID:',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: darkGreyColor,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 50),
          Text('Sat, 12 Mar 2022',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: darkGreyColor,
                  fontSize: 18,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Text(''),
          Text('Estimated Time: 07 Days',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: mainColorShades[9],
                  fontSize: 23,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Text('Received'),
                DottedBorder(
                    borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                    dashPattern: const [5, 5],
                    child: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 30,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Center(
            child: DottedBorder(
                borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                dashPattern: const [5, 10],
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                )),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Shipped'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Center(
            child: DottedBorder(
                borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                dashPattern: const [5, 10],
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                )),
          ),
          Text('Delivered'),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Center(
            child: DottedBorder(
                borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                dashPattern: const [5, 10],
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                )),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Text('Shipping Address'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
          Center(
            child: Text('Near post office, Tehsil, District Attock',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: darkGreyColor,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
              18.0,
            ),
            child: CustomGradientButton(
                buttonText: "Done".tr,
                buttonFunction: () => {Get.offAll(Home())}),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Text(
                'Back to Home'.tr,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: mainColor,
                    fontSize: 23,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              onTap: () => Get.offAll(Home()),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Does it have to  be the same decoration ?

Comment: yes same but needs to be in a line at the center position.

Answer (score 0):

Use row like

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    DottedBorder(
        borderType: BorderType.Circle,
        dashPattern: const [5, 10],
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
        )),
    SizedBox(
      width: 10,
    ),
    Text('Shipped'),
  ],
),
```

Behind the all item, you can include item using Stack

Answer (score 0):

Use [dotted_line](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_line) package too, and try this:

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                  child: DottedLine(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                  ),
                ),
                DottedBorder(
                    borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                    dashPattern: const [5, 10],
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                  child: DottedLine(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                  ),
                ),
                DottedBorder(
                    borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                    dashPattern: const [5, 10],
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                  child: DottedLine(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                  ),
                ),
                DottedBorder(
                    borderType: BorderType.Circle,
                    dashPattern: const [5, 10],
                    child: Container(
                      height: 20,
                      width: 20,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    )),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                  child: DottedLine(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 16,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text('Received'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 40,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text('Received'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 50,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text('Received'),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
```